# Webform Rule to Change Component Value

Tags: 7, rules, webforms

Does anyone know a way to change the value of a webform component after the submission is updated using rules?

For example:

Rule Triggers on Event: Webform Submission is Updated

Action: Change webform component value to X

Export of the Rule I have so far:

```
{ "rules_internship_agreement_form_updated" : {
  "LABEL" : "Internship Agreement Form Updated",
  "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
  "OWNER" : "rules",
  "REQUIRES" : [ "webform_rules", "rules", "php" ],
  "ON" : { "webform_rules_update" : [] },
  "IF" : [
  { "webform_has_id" : {
      "form_id" : [ "form-id" ],
      "selected_webform" : { "value" : { "webform-client-form-2" : "webform-client-form-2" } }
    }
  }
],
"DO" : [
  { "component_rules_check_internship_approvals_and_send_emails" : {
      "USING" : {
        "user_data" : [ "user" ],
        "faculty_approval" : "[data:faculty_approval-value]",
        "preceptor_approval" : "[data:preceptor_approval-value]",
        "student_email" : "[data:student_email-value]",
        "faculty_email" : "[data:faculty_email-value]",
        "preceptor_email" : "[data:preceptor_email-value]"
      },
      "PROVIDE" : {
        "faculty_approval" : { "faculty_approval" : "Faculty Approval" },
        "preceptor_approval" : { "preceptor_approval" : "Preceptor Approval" }
      }
    }
  },
  { "php_eval" : { "code" : "drupal_set_message($data[\u0027components\u0027][\u0027faculty_approval\u0027][\u0027value\u0027][0], \u0027status\u0027);" } }
]
}
}
```

So most of the middle part can be ignored, that's part of my conditional that is working, I just need the final "DO" or action where php_eval is.  Currently it is setting a drupal message, I would like that final action to instead, change the value of data:faculty_approval-value to a value (in my case I actually just want it blank).  If it can be done without custom php code execution, that would be great, but willing to do that if needed.

Comment: If you have specific field conditions that trigger the change- you might be able to avoid Rules and use Webform Conditional.  If you're using Webform v7.x-4.x, it's included/built-in; if you're using an older version of Webform, you'll need the separate module.  See https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/building-conditional-webforms-in-drupal-7/ for example of setting up conditionals.

Comment: are you sure "Webform Submission is Updated" is an existing event?

Comment: I have the latest version, so I don't need conditional.  Even so, if I could find the action or execute php code that would change the value on any webform that is updated, I could get it to work the way I need it to, so not looking for the conditional here.

And Yes Pierre, I am sure Webform Submission is Updated is an existing event as I have it currently set and it works with displaying a message.  I just can't get it to change the component value.

Comment: ok, merci for clarifying that. Please include an export of the rule you have so far (to display such message), by editiing your question. And then try to describe the missing "piece(s)" in your rule.